# Android email redirect is not working as expected

Tags: android, email

I want to make a button where on click the user to be redirected to email with exact email set as recipient, but this function is not working, in contrast the subject field is working

```
@Composable
fun sendEmail(emailIds: Array<String> =  arrayOf("Some email")) {
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO)
intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"))
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailIds);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "somesubject")
val context = LocalContext.current
Button(onClick = {
    startActivity(context, intent, null) }
) {
    Text("BUTTON")
} 
 }
```

this line is not working `intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailIds);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL with an array of recipients

```
val emailIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO).apply {
            data = Uri.parse("mailto:")
            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, arrayOf("email@email.com"))
            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject")
            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "body")
        }
```